# Advantages of static typing?

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, static-typing

I'm not claiming static typing is best, just wondering what advantages it really has. I thought they were:

- faster code
- catching some errors early

Looking at my own use (in Java), I'm mostly working for the compiler. When it catches a type error it's usually just an error in the *type*, not a code error - in fact, I can't recall it ever catching an actual bug (though it probably has).

Sometimes, I've gone through code to tighten up the types - for example, there may be a set of classes implementing some interface I, and so a field that can hold any of those classes is given type I. But this can be over-broad: sometimes there's also some fields that can only hold a subset of those classes, so the type system can be tightened by creating a new interface J, implemented only by that subset of classes, and those field are given type J.  While this is more "correct", it is incredibly *tedious*, and quite brittle if something changes.

So, I think faster code is the main benefit for static typing in mainstream compiled languages (Java, C#, C, C++, objective-C), and type-safety is a far second - though there's also some niches where type-safety is extremely helpful, such as ml languages for integrated circuit verification. I've also heard that static typing is important in databases.

But I think there's one other advantage:

- documentation

Documentation in that you can look at a method, and know what valid arguments are. And for auto-generated docs, the argument types are hyperlinked to the interface and implementations available. I don't think this is a killer-advantage, but it is a real one.

Obviously, python and ruby etc do great without static typing. I'm just wondering what the advantages of it are - what do you think? What's your experience?

Comment: after seeing so much stringly-typed code ( http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html #7 ) its more of a religios string errr thing. But as the website already says: "Excessively stringly typed code is usually a pain to understand and detonates at runtime with errors that the compiler would normally find. " its just a safety net sometimes.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that most of the tedium comes from *manifest* typing, which is when the compiler makes you explicitly tell it what types you're using. Many statically typed languages, such as OCaml and C#, can do much of this work for you.

Answer (score 4):

The Java static type system is an inexpressive, obsolete approach to static typing nearly 40 years out of date. Modern static typing allows for rich specification of invariants that code should satisfy, with the machine able to provide proofs for those invariants. Languages such as Haskell, Agda and ADA illustrate how types can be used to do serious software verification with relatively little cost (compared to e.g. testing).

So, besides the obvious benefit of having more information for the compiler, leading to faster code than is possible without static types, the fact is that modern type systems are significant tools for computer-aided verification of software. Something that you just won't see if the only type system you use is Java.

Answer (score 0):

By using static typing you are indicating what type of data you should be expected in a variable. With non-static you have to check the data type before performing processing. For example, you might expect an integer to be past to your method, but there is nothing to stop someone passing in a string.  This is opening yourself up to a world of pain IMHO.